# Bash File Triggered by SMS will not also trigger GPIO

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, sms, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I cannot get my Raspberry Pi 3 b+ to activate a GPIO pin (trigger relay) while within a bash file.

I am using gammu-smsd to receive a text message (SMS) from a GSM shield that is plugged into the header of the Pi. Gammu-smsd runs on receive the following code, I have it working other than activating the GPIO pin to trigger a relay. 
``
`#!/bin/sh`
`from=$SMS_1_NUMBER`
`message=$SMS_1_TEXT`
`reply=""`

`if [ "$message" = "Drop" ] ; then`

```
`echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export` 
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction`
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value`
`sleep 5`
`echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value `
`reply="Yes Sir, Done"  `
```

`else`
   `reply="Wrong Command, not sure how to process"`
`fi`

`echo "$reply" | gammu-smsd-inject TEXT "$from"`

I am expecting the GPIO 18 pin to become active, sleep 5 seconds and then shut back off.

Comment: Why do you use backticks to invoke commands?

Comment: I was trying to format my code for this site... Ignore all back tics

Comment: Found a problem 18 is actually 12 somehow.... Board vs something else... So I have the gpio pins working via python still no gpio via bash